# How to delete a record without immediate database effect

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

In a [precedent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56092261/how-to-create-a-record-without-saving-it-in-database), I was looking for the `BaseModel.new` method to behave like the `create` method from ORM, but without writing changes in the database.

Does the same method exist, but acting like `unlink`? I would like to delete a record from my recordset in an `onchange` call. I don't want the record to be delete at once, but only when the user will press the `Save` button.

Thank you a lot in advance!

---

For more information about why I want this feature:

I am using the `stock` module of Odoo. In a `Picking`, I want to dynamically change the reserved products (tracked by unique serial number) which means add some new `move_line`s and delete some of the existing ones.

I cannot simply change the `lot_id` as some `move_line`s with this `lot_id` may be reserved in another `Picking` (or at least, I didn't find how to do this neatly).

By changing the `lot_id` or doing `selected_move_id.move_line_ids.new({...})` in my `onchange` method, I can add the new ones. Now I would like to delete the existing ones that I don't need anymore. I would like to delete them the same way as if the user would have press the `trash` icon on the corresponding line.

Comment: what do you mean by only when user presses `save`?

Comment: I mean when you are editing the model containing the recordset, in the top left corner of the page, you can Edit and then Save or Discard.
For example, if I edit a model, then I press the trash icon of a list, and then click the Discard button, the deleted line re-appears (it has not been deleted in database).

Comment: I just edited my question, is it clearer ?

Comment: You mean when you edit a `x_to_many field` ?!!

Comment: AFAIK there is no such thing in Odoo. But I don't quite get why you'd need something like this. Could you elaborate on why you need this?

Comment: Exactly, yes, like `move_line_ids` from a `StockMove`.

Comment: @jzeta I want to simulate the behaviour of the trash button from a tree view, from an onchange call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something similar in `Odoo 12` and it worked fine:

```py
# I change the partner for testing different cases
@api.onchange('partner_id')
def onchage_p(self):
    """ remove moves have less then 5 units"""
    # create empty record set to hold valid records
    new_recs = self.env['stock.move']
    for move in self.move_ids_without_package:
        # keep only record that greater than 5
        if move.product_uom_qty > 5:
            new_recs += move

    # reassign it to the field. 
    self.move_ids_without_package = new_recs
```

When I debugged the `write` call on `stock.picking` the `delete cammand` 
was passed for all saved moves: `[...,[2, move_id, False]]`

The framework is able to detect that a record was removed from the original `recordset` and this is why the command was added.

So the basic Idea is create a new `recordset` that contains valid records assign it again to the one2many field.

Comment: That's what I want, but this solution empties my list as it losts all the other `move_line_id` when doing the affectation. That's why I'm looking for something similar to `new` (which would be equivalent to `= [(0, '_', {...})]`.

Comment: Interesting question mmm, I will try to find another solution ^^.

Comment: you have a lot of cases too if the record is not saved, the record is saved. the record is edited ?!!! a lot

Comment: Yes I know ^^ Thank you a lot for your time !

Comment: Could you give me the part in the code wḧich is called when we click the `trash` icon ? I cannot find it (I may be missing something trivial). Maybe it would help me understand how this works ?

Comment: No when you click on trash every thing is don in the client side, it's just going to switch the command of that line to `2` or remove it. no need to contact the server for that